Testing Selenium con python: Cuando se abre el navegador Chrome no veo el sitio web que estoy probando
escribo a la desesperada ya que no sé que más puedo hacer. Estoy aprendiendo Selenium con Python, me encuentro con la siguiente situación la cual no consigo resolver a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.
Al desarrollar un test simple consigo ejecutarlo por completo y de forma correcta. Lo que no consigo es ver la web en la que se esta haciendo el test, se levanta el navegador y me salta en la pestaña del navegador "Elige tu buscador" adjunto imagen, he comprobado que la URL se carga de forma correcta pero no la puedo ver a no ser que le de de forma manual quitando esa notificación. ¿HAY ALGUNA POSIBILIDAD DE SALTARSE ESO?. He probado añadir unas opciones al webdriver pero no encuentro la solución. Alguien que me ayude por favor.


Adjunto captura de lo que me sale y mi código.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
import time
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-first-run")  # Para evitar la primera ejecución
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # Evitar el problema DevToolsActivePort
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-background-networking")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-background-timer-throttling")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

def test_prueba_inicial():
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")

    titulo = driver.title
    assert titulo == "Google"
    time.sleep(10)


Para investigar el problema y probar una solución tendria que retipear todo tu código a partir de la imagen que publicas. Nadie va a hacer eso. Edita tu pregunta y pon el código como texto si quieres recibir ayuda.

Gracias de antemano, listo retipeado.  a ver si tengo suerte y alguien puede ayudarme.

@FcoP ¿puede ser que te este faltando ejecutar la función test_prueba_inicial()?

@Marcos , he encontrado la solución!!!. la pongo por si os sirve.
options = ChromeOptions() options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")
